# не понимаю почему не работает функция автоматического движения влево-вправо

Tags: python, pygame

в функции avto

```
from pygame import *

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("jungles.ogg")
mixer.music.play()




window = display.set_mode((1000,700)) #oкнo
display.set_caption('Догонялки')



clock = time.Clock()

bg = transform.scale(image.load('background.jpg'),(1000,700)) #фон
treasure = transform.scale(image.load('treasure.png'),(100,70))


class Hero:
    def __init__(self,x,y):


        self.x=x

        self.y=y

        self.hero = transform.scale(image.load('hero.png'),(100, 70))

        global rect1
        rect1 = self.hero.get_rect()

    def upravlenie(self):
        k_s = key.get_pressed()
        if k_s[K_LEFT] and self.x > 0:
            self.x -= 10
        elif k_s[K_RIGHT] and self.x < 900:
            self.x += 10
        if k_s[K_UP] and self.y > 0:
            self.y -= 10
        elif k_s[K_DOWN] and self.y < 600:
            self.y += 10
    def render(self):
        window.blit(self.hero, (self.x,self.y))
          
class Cyborg:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x + 23

        self.y = y

        self.cyborg = transform.scale(image.load('cyborg.png'),(100, 70))

        global rect2
        rect2 = self.cyborg.get_rect()

    def avto(self):
        if self.x > 700 and self.x <= 850:
            self.x -= 5 
        if self.x == 700:
            if self.x != 850:
                self.x += 5
        print(self.x)
    def render(self):
        window.blit(self.cyborg, (self.x, self.y))

hero = Hero(0, 600)
cyborg = Cyborg(777,500)


game = True #переключатель для завершения цикла игры

while game != False:
    window.blit(bg,(0,0))
    window.blit(treasure,(850, 600))
    hero.render()
    hero.upravlenie()
    cyborg.render()
    cyborg.avto()
    
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            game = False
    display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавил перечисление для описания состояния

Оно используется, чтобы определить в какое направление движется робот

Пример:

```
import enum

...

class StateEnum(enum.Enum):
    NONE = enum.auto()
    MOVE_RIGHT = enum.auto()
    MOVE_LEFT = enum.auto()


class Cyborg:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x + 23
        self.y = y

        self.state = StateEnum.MOVE_RIGHT

        self.cyborg = transform.scale(image.load('cyborg.png'), (100, 70))

        global rect2
        rect2 = self.cyborg.get_rect()

    def update_state(self):
        if self.x >= 850:
            self.state = StateEnum.MOVE_LEFT
        elif self.x <= 700:
            self.state = StateEnum.MOVE_RIGHT

    def avto(self):
        if self.state == StateEnum.MOVE_LEFT:
            self.x -= 5
        elif self.state == StateEnum.MOVE_RIGHT:
            self.x += 5

        self.update_state()

        print(self.state, self.x)

    def render(self):
        window.blit(self.cyborg, (self.x, self.y))
```

Comment: Ну всё спасибо братан обнял поднял всё ништяк от души братка рахмет рахмет сау бол волейбол баскетбол гандбол

Comment: @exception, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)